# android uncheck ratingbar

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am trying to `check/uncheck` `RatingBar` but apparently its not unchecking star. I am able to set star but unchecking is not working.

```
<RatingBar android:id="@+id/bookmarks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="1"
    android:rating="0" 
    android:stepSize="1"
     />

    bookmarkStar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener()
                {

        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser)
                {


          if(beforeRating == 1.0)
          {
            bookmarkStar.setRating(0);
          }
          else
          {
           bookmarkStar.setRating(1);
           }

          }
          });
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Likely a precision issue - have you tried not comparing it to a double value? Or even something like: `bookmarkStar.setRating(beforeRating != 0 ? 0 : 1);`?

Comment: I tried

bookmarkStar.setRating(beforeRating != 0 ? 0 : 1);

Problem appears to be different. I placed a breakpoint inside onrating changed. Once rating is set and star is clicked it doesn't go onratingchanged....I am lost

Comment: Are you updating `beforeRating` anywhere? If not then it makes sense your rating never changes, as the condition you test will always yield the same result.

Comment: Regardless of that shouldn't onratingchanged be called as its inside changelistner? Why debug doesn't show this part being executed?

Comment: I got it working. I think its strange but may be not.

I doesn't act like a button. To remove rating drag your finger to left. If you press and lift your finger nothing happens :S

Comment: That's standard behavior of the RatingBar. You might be better of with a ToggleButton or Checkbox (optionally with a statelist drawable as background to show a star) if you just want to have checked/unchecked states.